# Uri add text from edittext to link

Tags: java, android

```html
  findNumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://wwww.whitepages.ca/phone/" + phoneNumber.getText());
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

When I do that it only opened up "http://www.whitepages.com/phone/"

Comment: What is your question? it isn't clear from the question what your issue is, add more information so that people can help you better.

Comment: why the definition of the uri and the intent is not in onClick method?